# One line for loop a = a*b + x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, for-loop, one-liner

I have the following for loop:

```
a = 0
b = 100
for x in my_list:
  a = a * b + x
return a
```

My question is can I write it in single line.

I have tried:

```
a = my_list[0]
return sum((a*b + x) for x in my_list)
```

But is not doing what I want to.

Comment: I can't think of a way to write it in a single line, and even if someone else can think of a "clever" way to do so, I highly doubt that it would make the code more convenient to work with.

Comment: “But is not doing what I want to.”  What do you want it to do?

Comment: To perform the result as above, and in the end return me "a", I have just edited it

Comment: Is `my_list` totally arbitrary?

Comment: It is of consecutive numbers b/w 1000 and 2000

Comment: @IIK then this can be solved analytically in one formula in O(1)

Comment: I am trying to use Horner's scheme

Comment: Why do you want to write it on a single line? Note, Python doesn't *have one-line for loops*, except for `for x in whatever: do_something_with(x)`, but if you are asking about using a comprehension construct, that isn't how you should be thinking about them. List comprehensions, etc, express *mapping/filtering* operations on iterables to yield some result, a list, dict, set, or generator. What you have here is not a mapping/filtering operation, it's an accumulation. The Pythonic way to do that is with a for-loop.

Comment: Write down a recursive formula. In your case it would be `f(n) = f(n-1)*b + x0 + n - 1` and `f(0)=0`. (I might be off-by one here), now either use your math skills or use [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=6060d322713797e84f598ea25c812cab) to derive a closed for expression.

Comment: Note that the duplicate question is wrong since the Op doesn't ask for accumulate but for reduce behaviour...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
res = reduce(lambda a, x: a * b + x, my_list, 0)
```

Comment: You got there before me! As a functional programmer at heart it always saddens me that so vital a tool as `reduce` has to be imported in Python.

Comment: It looks clever but I can't help noticing that one of the inputs (`my_list`) is entirely missing...

Comment: It was not always the case, but they though there were already too much names in the globals namespace :)

Comment: @alani yeah typo, forgot the input iterable xD

Comment: @hl037_ actually, Guido wanted to remove `map`, `filter` and `reduce` entirely. `map`/`filter` is almost always better as a comprehension construct, and `reduce` is "usually more clear as a loop" according to Guido. Basically, Python is not a functional programming language, rather, it picks and chooses constructs from functional programming languages which it likes, but at it's core, it's a very imperative language

Comment: I came up with a much uglier solution.  I'm so glad I saw this post before posting mine.  Beautiful.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga Interesting to know. I personnally largely prefer the functionnal style, it is what give so much power to this language. for map / filter, I agree but reduce is really beautiful...

Answer (score -3):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = 0
b = 100
[print(a * b + x) for x in my_list]
```

But as a = 0, you will show only your list